# R: manipulate dataframe cell using named numeric vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to (manually) overwrite cells in column `x` of the dataframe `df`. But R produces an error. Consider

```
m = 1:2
n = 3:4
names(m)= c("o", "we")
names(n)= c("bn","lt")
s = c( "bb", "cc") 
b = c( FALSE, TRUE)
df = data.frame( s, b)
df$x= list(m,n)
```

Now replace column x first row:

```
k = 5:6
names(k)= c("jh","jh")
df[1,"x"] = k  ## error occurs here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `df$x[[1]] = k`

Since you are using a data frame you can not speak of columns and rows.. so you have to access the elements of the data frame with `$` instead of `"x"`.

Further, you are using lists in your data frame. You should access the elements of a list with `[[1]]` or any other position of the element in the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: data frames are really lists so you can use `df[['x']][[1]]` for the same effect.